# ASP.Net Web Service: What object type to use as collection of parameters?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

Here's the scenario:

There's a web service (.asmx) that contains a single method which takes in a string specifying  where to get some information, and a list of parameters, which could be different based upon what was entered for the first value.

For example, a call might look like:

```
WebserviceMethod("PeopleSearch", { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" })
```

What kind of collection would I use for that second parameter?  It's really just a simple dictionary/hashtable, but I don't believe Dictionary is serializable

Comment: If the service doesn't exist  yet, then why not use WCF?

Comment: are the parameter values in the collection always going to be strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, dictionary isn't serialisable, so create your own:

```
Class secondParam{
    Public string key { get: set; }
    Public string value { get; set; }
}
```

And accept a List as your second parameter. ( or an array if you wish )

Comment: This is what I ended up implementing (plus marking it as [Serializable]) after some more research

Comment: Great. As a side note, it looks like you are writing a "generic" web service method, where the first parameter is the actual function that you wish to call and the second has the parameters. As a general rule you probably want to avoid doing this, instead create a new method for each different call that you wish to make. This'll enforce type safety, making sure that you pass through the right parameters, and also make it easier to comment and more maintainable code :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can easily implement it as a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  There are also a [number](http://www.dacris.com/blog/2010/07/31/c-serializable-dictionary-a-working-example/)  [of](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx)  [implementations](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/source/browse/trunk/MSNPSHARP_DEV/MSNPSharp/IO/SerializableDictionary.cs?spec=svn2678&r=2678) you can grab off the Internet.

Comment: I don't believe KVP is serializable

Comment: Ack - you're right.  Looking back at my project, I re-implemented it manually with the [Serializable] attribute.  Silly me not checking the namespaces.

Comment: Actually, looking at MSDN (and validating with a WCF interface), Dictionary IS serializable!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx